# Log Severity not correct in google cloud console

Tags: python, console, fastapi, google-cloud-logging, log-level

I have a FastApi application which is running on Google Kubernetes engine. Initially, Uvicorn startup logs were being displayed with Severity ERROR in the google console. I added the following logging config file to the uvicorn.run to solve it. Post adding the logging config file to Uvicorn, this issue was solved and I am facing another issue that Errors and Warning are also showing as Severity INFO in google cloud console.

Before adding uvicorn_log.config :
[image]

To solve the above issue, I added following logging config file to uvicorn.run:

```
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5021, log_config='uvicorn_log.config')
```

config file content:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=console

[formatters]
keys=generic

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET

handlers=console


[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_generic]
format= %(message)s
```

In my logger module I am using google.cloud.logging library as below:

```
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()
logging.error("This appears with severity INFO in google console")
```

I am not able to find what in the config file is overriding the severity level of python logger. Any suggestion and idea is much appreciated

Comment: Initially, Uvicorn startup logs were being displayed with Severity ERROR in the google console. Post adding the logging config file to Uvicorn, this issue was solved and you are facing another issue that Errors and Warning are also showing as Severity INFO.

Comment: This might be due to the Configfile and  Logger module which you are using. Update  this  [FastAPI unicorn configfile](https://gist.github.com/liviaerxin/d320e33cbcddcc5df76dd92948e5be3b#fastapi-and-uvicorn-logging) as per your requirement  and change the  logger module accordingly as per this  [log entries doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#log-entries) which is having multiple modules and try it.  Check out these [Uvicorn log settings](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging) also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following configuration file. Essentially, my solution involved redirecting uvicorn logs to standard output(to prevent them appearing as error in GCP console) while leaving the root logger configuration intact.

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
  default:
    format: '%(message)s'
handlers:
  default:
    formatter: default
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

loggers:
  uvicorn.error:
    level: INFO
    handlers:
      - default
    propagate: no
  uvicorn.access:
    level: INFO
    handlers:
      - default
    propagate: no
```